# Reading xlsx file steam stuck with A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))

Tags: c#, excel

i am using using OfficeOpenXml; for reading excel file and its working fine with other reading file but for one perticular file i got above mention error.

[image: check this image]

```
public ReadExcelFile(Stream stream, string worksheet, List<ExcelColumnMapping> columnMapping, ITypeConvert typeConvert = null, int headerSize = 1)
{
    _stream = stream;
    _excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream);
    _worksheet = _excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[worksheet];
    _headerSize = headerSize;
    _rowCount = headerSize + 1;
    var mapping = ColumnMappingRowNumber(columnMapping);
    _resultColumnNumbersAndTypes = mapping.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Item2, x.Item3, x.Item4)).ToList();
    _converter = typeConvert ?? new ExcelTypeConvert();
    ReadLineValues();

}
```

Comment: Is this file opening correctly with Microsoft Excel etc?

Comment: yes. its should work with microsoft excel